# Nothing is showing up on my Recyclerview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I can't figure out why nothing is being displayed in my `RecyclerView`. All I do is press a button and I want to be navigated to `Activity` where I will see the list of my followers. Below is my code:

XML Layout:

follow_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/follow_list_layout_id"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/follow_toolbar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--<include layout="@layout/include_progress_overlay"/>-->

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/follow_list"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

follow_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/follower_card_view">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp">

    <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
        android:id="@+id/follower_profile_picture"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        fresco:placeholderImageScaleType="centerCrop"
        fresco:placeholderImage="@mipmap/blank_prof_pic"
        fresco:roundedCornerRadius="5dp"
        fresco:roundAsCircle="true"
        />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="72dp"
            android:id="@+id/follower_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/follower_checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter:

```
public class FollowerRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FollowerRecyclerViewAdapter.FollowerViewHolder>{

    private List<User> followers;

    public void setFollowers(List<User> followers) {
        this.followers = followers;
    }

    public static User containsId(List<User> list, String id) {
        for (User object : list) {
            if (object.getUserId().equals(id)) {
                return object;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public FollowerRecyclerViewAdapter(List<User> followers) {
        this.followers = followers;
    }

    public List<User> getFollowers(){
        return this.followers;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return followers.size();
    }

    public static class FollowerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cardViewfollower;
        TextView name;
        CheckBox isFollowingCheckBox;
        SimpleDraweeView followerProfilePhoto;

        FollowerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cardViewfollower = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.follower_card_view);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.follower_name);
            followerProfilePhoto = (SimpleDraweeView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.follower_profile_picture);
            isFollowingCheckBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.follower_checkbox);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FollowerViewHolder followerViewHolder, int i) {
        final User currentItem = getItem(i);
        followerViewHolder.name.setText(currentItem.getName());
        DraweeController controller = TabsUtil.getImage(currentItem.getUserId());
        RoundingParams roundingParams = RoundingParams.fromCornersRadius(5f);
        roundingParams.setRoundAsCircle(true);
        followerViewHolder.followerProfilePhoto.getHierarchy().setRoundingParams(roundingParams);
        followerViewHolder.followerProfilePhoto.setController(controller);
    }

    @Override
    public FollowerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.follower_item, viewGroup, false);
        FollowerViewHolder pvh = new FollowerViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    private User getItem(int position)
    {
        return followers.get(position);
    }

    public void add(User follower){
        for(int i = 0; i < followers.size(); i++) {
            if(follower.getId().equals(followers.get(i).getId())) {
                return;
            }
        }
        followers.add(follower);
        notifyItemInserted(followers.size() + 1);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(followers.size() + 1, followers.size());
    }

    public void remove(Follower item) {
        int position = followers.indexOf(item);
        followers.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }
```

Class to show Followers:

```
public class FollowingList extends AppCompatActivity {

    FireBaseApplication application;
    DatabaseQuery databaseQuery;
    View progressOverlay;
    String posterUserId;
    String posterName;
    String postStatus;
    String postTimeStamp;
    String postTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.follow_list);
        application = ((FireBaseApplication) getApplication());
        databaseQuery = new DatabaseQuery(this);

        //Set up action bar
        setupActionBar();

        progressOverlay = findViewById(R.id.progress_overlay);
        //AndroidUtils.animateView(progressOverlay, View.VISIBLE, 0.9f, 200);
        setupActivity(savedInstanceState);

        //All we need to do is render the page now
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.follow_list);

        RecyclerView.ItemAnimator animator = recyclerView.getItemAnimator();
        if (animator instanceof SimpleItemAnimator) {
            ((SimpleItemAnimator) animator).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
        }
        //Assuming we refresh the followers list, we have to make sure that new followers are loaded
        application.getFollowingRecyclerViewAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(application.getFollowingRecyclerViewAdapter());
    }

    private void setupActionBar(){
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.follow_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //Back bar enabled
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        //Toggle bar enabled
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why my `RecyclerView` isn't showing any of my `followers` but any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why you haven't declared and initialized your adapter? You should have `FollowerRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new FollowerRecyclerViewAdapter(folowers);` then `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)`;

Comment: I have actually but that is in another part of the code that is not shown sorry. Any other ideas?